# No power in r line after changed thermostat

Tags: furnace, nest

I have a carrier furnace 2008, just changed my old thermostat to new nest thermostat, forgot to turn off the power. Now I have no power on my r line, checked short fuse still good, red light in front of furnace still on, I am not sure why I lost power to the r line. My furnace was working fine yesterday. Checked with nest supporting line, nest base was not a problem. Help

Comment: If you jumper R to W, does the furnace run?

Comment: How are you checking for "power"?  Do you mean that the thermostat does not turn on, or that you're not measuring 24 volts on the wire? How did you wire the new thermostat?  Does the thermostat need a `C` wire? If so, did you hook up a `C` wire?

Comment: I crossed  the r and c wire, furnace did not turn on,

Comment: Yes I need the c wire. I connected the wire to the thermostat correctly.  The r wire has low voltage.  The  red light  in the  control panels blink when I crossed the r and c wire.  The blinking frequency usually tell how to trouble shoot for the problem.

Comment: Do you mean you're crossing R and W @Trien ?

Comment: You probably short-circuited the 24V transformer so, if you're lucky, you may just have to replace a blown fuse, if you're very lucky, it's also an automotive kind so super-easy to find and replace, if you're not may have damaged the transformer's  coil so you have to replace whole transformer.

Answer (score 0):

check for 24 volts at the furnace. Some carrier boards will have a lit led even if the 24 volt circuit is non functioning. I don't recommend using a contact probe. I always recommend using a muti-meter. 
 Check from R to C. your looking for 24 volts. if no voltage, then check 3/5 amp fuse on board. If fuse is good, check voltage from transformer. 
 If you do have voltage From R to C. put a jumper from R to G and see if the fan comes on. if fan comes on, then you know the issue is at the thermostat somewhere.
 I hope this helps..